# Properly Declare a List Collection?

Tags: powershell

In Powershell V4, how would I properly declare a `List<>` collection?

I tried declaring it like this

```powershell
$listCollection = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'
```

It didn't work and gave me errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Powershell, you need to use square brackets `[...]` when specifying the type of the list's items:

```powershell
PS > $listCollection = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]  
PS > $listCollection.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                 
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                 
True     True     List`1                                   System.Object            


PS >
```

Note that this is different from C#, which would use angle brackets `<...>`.